# Clarification question about quotient ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Consider the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, and any ideal $I \subset R$ with $I = (r)$. Apparantly it is the case that 
$$
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(r) \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 + 3, r). 
$$

This step is often used in proofs in which you need to simplify the quotientring.

Can anyone explain precisely the steps to see that the above is true? 
I have thought of the third isomorphism theorem, or the first isomorphism theorem with $\phi: f \mapsto f(\sqrt{3})$, but I cannot work out the specifics. It is often presented as a trivial fact, without proof, so that's why I am wondering if there is any trick to quickly establish that this is true?

Comment: You probably want $I$ to be generated by elements in $\mathbb{Z}$, otherwise the right hand side doesn't make much sense. But then it should be a straightforward computation.

Comment: Yeah Indeed it is generated by one element

Comment: You still want $r\in \mathbb{Z}$ otherwise $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 + 3, r)$ doesn't make sense. The second claim is just wrong: take $r=3$, then you have  $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 + 3, 3)=\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 , 3)$ which has 9 elements  but $ \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 + 3, X)= \mathbb{Z}[X]/(3, X)$ has only 3 elements.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, the second claim was wrong, apologies I have removed it. But I still don't see how the first claim works. Also why necessarily $r \in \mathbb{Z}$? For example what about if $r = \sqrt{-3}$, and we have $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 + 3, \sqrt{-3})$?

Comment: The ideal $I$ appearing  in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ must consist of polynomials in $x$ with integer coefficients. This is not the case for $r=r(x)=\sqrt{-3}$.

Comment: No I am talking about an ideal of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, not $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. $(\sqrt{-3})$ is an example of this, since $\sqrt{-3} \in  \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ with coeffients $0,1,0, \ldots$.

Comment: @Sigurd The ideal $(X^2 + 3, \sqrt{-3})$ is not a subset set of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ because $\sqrt{-3} \notin \mathbb{Z}[X]$.  So the quotient you wrote in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2501775/clarification-question-about-quotient-ring-isomorphism#comment5167421_2501775) doesn't make sense.  That is what the other commenters have been trying to get across to you.  What you need to do instead is write $r = a + b \sqrt{-3}$.  Then $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]}{(a + b \sqrt{-3})} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(X^2 + 3, a + b X)}$.